# Mailcore2 can not access yahoo messages

Tags: objective-c, email, yahoo, mailcore2

I am able to access Inbox and Trash folder in Yahoo mail. But I can't access Drafts or Spam folder.
This is my error message:

```
2016-05-27 16:42:40.962 iOS UI Test[781:73868] checking account
2016-05-27 16:42:40.963 [781:480f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:81: start thread
2016-05-27 16:42:40.997 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:592: connect <mailcore::IMAPSession:0x12c615c50>
2016-05-27 16:42:42.715 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:615: ssl connect imap.mail.yahoo.com 993 2
2016-05-27 16:42:42.726 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:683: connect ok
2016-05-27 16:42:42.726 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:723: login
2016-05-27 16:42:44.964 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:992: login ok
2016-05-27 16:42:44.965 iOS UI Test[781:73868] finished checking account.
2016-05-27 16:42:44.967 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1079: select
2016-05-27 16:42:44.967 iOS UI Test[781:73930] MCOIMAPSession: [1] 5 SELECT Drafts

2016-05-27 16:42:45.561 iOS App[781:73930] MCOIMAPSession: [0] 5 BAD [TRYCREATE] SELECT error - Folder does not exist or server encountered an error

2016-05-27 16:42:45.562 [781:480f] MCIMAPSession.cpp:1083: select error : 9
2016-05-27 16:42:46.663 [781:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:215: trying to quit 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:42:46.663 [781:480f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:102: stopping 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:42:46.664 [781:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:230: thread stopped 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:42:46.664 [781:480f] MCOperationQueue.cpp:151: cleanup thread 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:43:19.664 [781:2017] MCOperationQueue.cpp:81: start thread
2016-05-27 16:43:20.770 [781:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:215: trying to quit 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:43:20.770 [781:2017] MCOperationQueue.cpp:102: stopping 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:43:20.770 [781:main] MCOperationQueue.cpp:230: thread stopped 0x17015a8e0
2016-05-27 16:43:20.770 [781:2017] MCOperationQueue.cpp:151: cleanup thread 0x17015a8e0
```

Must we special config in yahoo account?

Any help will be great appreciated.
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problems. I fill wrong name folder.
Server folder subscription status:
1. YMAIL: Draft, Inbox, Sent, Bulk Mail, Trash
2. GMAIL: Drafts, Inbox, Sent Mail, Spam, Trash, All Mail.
3. Outlook: Drafts, Inbox, Sent, Junk, Deleted.